# How to get the seed value from a random number generator in PHP

Tags: php, random, seed, srand

I would like to get the seed value after the `rand()` or `mt_rand()` is used. Essentially I want to store the seed so that I can use this seed to continue generating random numbers next time php is executed.

I need a repeatable behavior for unit testing/load testing... and different modules in my applications will use the same seed, so that the sequence of random numbers are generated are reproducible.

Thanks for your input. I couldn't find a method to get the seed. A Random number generator class that exposes the seed would be helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

If you need repeatable behavior, you should seed `rand()` or `mt_rand()` yourself using `srand()` or `mt_srand()` and store the seed that you use.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the only way to know what the seed in use is is to [specify it yourself](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
mt_srand($known_value)
```

Will set your seed to a repeatable value